# ALSA buffer underrun network audio

Tags: audio, alsa

I'm using Arch Linux ARM on an Olimex LIME2. Network speed tests between the device and NAS indicate > 450Mbps. I'm using an I2S Driver for audio output.

When playing 2 channel, 192kHz / 24bit material, I get the following:

1. Playing from USB stick: good.
2. Playing from NFS share: buffer underruns between 7 & 300 ms.
3. Playing from CIFS share: buffer underruns between 199 & 215 ms.

Where do I begin to track down the issue?

EDIT:
A. I'm testing with:

```
aplay -D default:CARD=sunxisndi2s "/mnt/nfs/06 - Rosie 192.wav"
```

B. 96kHz / 24bit material plays without issue over the network.

EDIT:
PING results:

```
64 bytes from 10.10.10.9: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.750 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.9: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.371 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.9: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.439 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.9: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=0.440 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.9: icmp_seq=5 ttl=128 time=0.362 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.9: icmp_seq=6 ttl=128 time=0.438 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.9: icmp_seq=7 ttl=128 time=0.441 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.9: icmp_seq=8 ttl=128 time=0.439 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.9: icmp_seq=9 ttl=128 time=0.440 ms
```

Comment: What matters is not the network's bandwidth but the latency. Try increasing the buffer size.

Comment: I edited the post to include some PING results. The latency seems good, is it not? Can you point me in the direction of which setting to adjust? I have this: 'net.ipv4.tcp_rmem= 10240 87380 12582912'

Comment: NFS is not implemented over ping packets. (And 400 ms is horrible.) Anyway, see `man aplay`.

Comment: I think this is 0.400 ms, not 400 ms. How can I test NFS or CIFS latency? I've read the aplay man page, but don't see how I could increase the buffer size. `If no buffer time and no buffer size is given then the maximal allowed buffer time but not more than 500ms is set.` Should be using the max buffer, right?